# QT QML error on loading qml file in another qml

Tags: qt, types, qml

I have a very strange behavior when trying to load a QML in another QML (both files in the same path)

Here is the part of the loading QML (that one with the ApplicationWindow)

```
Rectangle { 
            id: buttons1
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: root.buttons1Height
            color: "lightgray"
            RowLayout {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                spacing: 20
                Button1 { id: button1; height: root.buttons1Height * 0.6; icon: "abort"; onButtonClicked: { console.log("Button1 clicked") } }
            }
```

And the corresponding QML Button1

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Rectangle {
    id: button
    height: 100;
    width: height;
    radius: height / 2
    color: "white"
    border.width: 0
    border.color: "black"
    signal buttonClicked
    property string icon: ""
    Image {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "image://iconprovider/" + button.icon
        sourceSize.height: button.height
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: button.buttonClicked()
        onPressed: button.border.width = 2
        onReleased: button.border.width = 0
    }
}
```

That works fine, a button is displayed in main.qml.

However, a second QML file with completely identical content causes an error.

Again the the loading QML

```
Rectangle { 
            id: buttons1
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: root.buttons1Height
            color: "lightgray"
            RowLayout {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                spacing: 20
                IconButton { id: button1; height: root.buttons1Height * 0.6; icon: "abort"; onButtonClicked: { console.log("Button1 clicked") } }
            }
```

And the corresponding QML IconButton

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Rectangle {
    id: button
    height: 100;
    width: height;
    radius: height / 2
    color: "white"
    border.width: 0
    border.color: "black"
    signal buttonClicked
    property string icon: ""
    Image {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "image://iconprovider/" + button.icon
        sourceSize.height: button.height
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: button.buttonClicked()
        onPressed: button.border.width = 2
        onReleased: button.border.width = 0
    }
}
```

Error is

QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/screens/qml/x86/Test.qml:44:17: IconButton is not a type

But why - I only what to rename Button1 to IconButton?

Thanks and best regards
Arne

Comment: Did you actually include it in the QRC? (or add to RESOURCES in .pro file)

Answer (score 0):

now it works but I don't quite understand it. Main.qml is loaded via a resource.qrc entry

```
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/screens/qml/x86/Main.qml")));
```

[image]

IconButton was missing until now. After I have added the reference to the resource file it also it works.

I had read that to include other QMLs they only have to be in the same path or have to be made known via an include?

Comment: Adding QML source to the resource file means they get built into the executable. If you don't do that, then the QML files have to be present in the file system from where the executable is running.